# Create file with pipe character ("|") in filename on Ubuntu/Windows11 dual-boot machine

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, filenames

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and would like to create a file having the pipe character ("|") in its filename.  (Necessary to run some legacy code.)  Specifically, how do I identify and correct the pitfalls that are preventing me from doing so on certain drives of a Linux/Windows11 dual boot system?

I think dual-boot is an issue because I can successfully create such a file in some directories on my machine, but not those on disk drives that Windows can read (see below).  Someone else originally installed the operating systems, so I don't know what choices they made that could affect this question.

Here is what I've tried.  The attempt below works, so we know there's no fundamental objection from Linux:

```
xname@blackbox:~$ cd ~
xname@blackbox:~$ touch "|"
xname@blackbox:~$ ls -l "|"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xname xname 0 Feb  9 10:17 '|'
```

Likewise, I can successfully touch the file if I'm in the `/media` directory or in the `/media/xname` directory.

```
xname@blackbox:/media/xname$ cd /media
xname@blackbox:/media$ sudo touch "|"
xname@blackbox:/media$ cd /media/xname
xname@blackbox:/media/xname$ sudo touch "|"
xname@blackbox:/media/xname$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xname xname    0 Feb  9 11:35 '|'
drwxrwxrwx 1 xname xname 8192 Feb  8 17:25  cdisk
drwxrwxrwx 1 xname xname 4096 Feb  9 11:30  ddisk
```

You can see the permissions on `ddisk` above.  Its parent directory had an ACL when I originally got the machine, but I removed it using `setfacl -b ddisk` and then re-booted.

The touch attempt fails inside `ddisk` (and `cdisk`):

```
xname@blackbox:/media/xname$ cd /media/xname/ddisk
xname@blackbox:/media/xname/ddisk$ touch "this_works_fine"
xname@blackbox:/media/xname/ddisk$ touch "|"
touch: setting times of '|': No such file or directory
xname@blackbox:/media/xname/ddisk$ sudo touch "|"
touch: setting times of '|': No such file or directory
```

Perhaps part of the output of the `findmnt` command will be helpful:

```
TARGET                                   SOURCE           FSTYPE  OPTIONS
/                                        /dev/nvme0n1p5   ext4    rw,relatime,er
├─/media/xname/ddisk                     /dev/nvme1n1p2   fuseblk rw,nosuid,node
└─/media/xname/cdisk                     /dev/nvme0n1p3   fuseblk rw,nosuid,node
```

And here is the output of `mount | grep media`

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /media/xname/cdisk type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/nvme1n1p2 on /media/xname/ddisk type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Another puzzling thing about this machine that may be relevant:  When I sign in, I'm asked for a password for an account that is not `xname`.  I don't know where `xname` came from.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @roaima: Done!  Thanks.

Comment: Mmm  `fuseblk` isn't telling me anything helpful. I can create filenames containing `|` on ext4 and NTFS filesystems. I wonder if yours are vFAT or xFAT?

Comment: @roaima: I looked but could not get my arms around any way to tell if vFAT or xFAT is used by those disks.  It's a reasonable bet, though, as the machine started as Windows and then had Linux installed second.

Comment: I don't know of any other filesystem that prevents the use of `|`. (Windows OS does, but its filesystems do not.)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't really matter *which* DOS/Windows specific file-system you use;
they **all** forbid the following characters (per [this MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)) ....

Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), **except for the following:**

The following reserved characters:

- < less than
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical pipe or bar)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

I doubt that there's an abstraction layer that pulls those out irrespective of filesystem, but I'm obviously not an MS Employee and don't know for sure. I guess that all Windows-filesystems implement that limitation and it seems only logical that the linux-implementations of these honour those. I'd imagine that if you e.g. managed to create the file `*hey|there` on Linux and then booted windows and it were to run a `fsck` it would get quite upset. ;)

Comment: That's not right. The Windows interface (and API) forbids `|` but the NTFS filesystem does not. I have tested this just yesterday using Cygwin

Comment: "_I doubt that there's an abstraction layer_" - it's the Windows API. The section of documentation you quoted is a Naming Convention, not a hard requirement. The topic goes on to explain how to bypass this (otherwise enforced) naming convention for special cases

Comment: Further checking (again, on NTFS) the only characters from that list I _cannot_ put into a filename are `/` and `\ `. Windows Explorer on the other hand, struggles to list or otherwise do anything with files containing any of the listed characters.

Comment: This is all very helpful, thanks. It must be true that the filesystem on the offending disks is vFAT or xFAT and so therefore it is hopeless to seek a workaround.  There appears to be no other choice but to reformat `ddisk`. This will probably mean that Windows 11 won't be able afterwards to see the disk, but `cdisk` is still available for Windows-Linux file exchange, and so the price of reformatting is reasonable to pay.

Comment: @roaima - all your points may be valid, but for all intents an purposes it makes no sense to do something on Linux to an FS that *the other OS* then won't be happy with.

Comment: @IronPillow - I think that's a very wise decision.

Comment: Bring recommended not to do something is not necessarily the same as being unable to do it. You are saying something cannot be done; I'm pointing out that this is incorrect

Comment: That's NOT what I'm saying. I'm saying is that if the OS for which the partition is designed can't handle certain file names not to put them there. Insisting that something is OK because it *can* be done is just silly.

Comment: @ChrisDavies: You should be able to get / with enough determination involving native API calls. You may have to set a registry key to tell it to get out of the way, like you have to do to actually use case sensitive now.

Comment: @Joshua if you're mentioning the windows registry then you are mixing up NTFS with Windows and its abstraction layer. One is far more restrictive than the other, but without an OS that lets me attempt to place a filename containing `/` I'll never know it's possible without reading the NTFS specification

Comment: @ChrisDavies: At the NTCreateFile level the only absolutely forbidden character is \; even nulls work. However in more recent Windows versions they added blocks for abuse of the native APIs by viruses and registry switches to turn them off. If you try it on NT4 those blocks aren't there and / works just fine.

Comment: This list of reserved characters applies to the FAT filesystem though. I don't think NtCreateFile will bypass it on FAT.